# How to solve this error android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!title.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !message.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FcmNotificationsSender notificationsSender=new FcmNotificationsSender( "/topics/all",title.getText().toString(),message.getText().toString()
               ,(Activity)getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.this);
```

notificationsSender.SendNotifications();
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

```
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change those `MainActivity.this` to `view.getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

(Activity)getApplicationContext() this line is the issue. Just remove (Activity) casting on app context.